# Einbürgerungstest results waiting time

Tags: germany, citizenship, eu-citizens, europe, german-citizens

Has anyone from Berlin recently appeared for the Einbürgerungstest? What would be the approximate time for receiving back the results?

I gave the exam in Volkhochschule Marzahn, Berlin and we were only around 10 people in total.

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the approximate time for receiving back the results?

4 weeks.

---

> **Prüfungsergebnis**
>
> - Das BAMF schickt Ihnen in der Regel **vier Wochen** nach dem Einbürgerungstest das Ergebnis per Post zu.
> - Falls Sie nach diesem Zeitraum noch kein Ergebnis erhalten haben, wenden Sie sich bitte direkt an die Regionalstelle des BAMF in Berlin.
> - Wenn Sie bei einer Einbürgerungsbehörde bereits einen Einbürgerungsantrag gestellt haben, wird die Behörde über Ihr Prüfungsergebnis informiert.
>
> > **exam result**
> >
> > - The BAMF usually sends you the result by post **four weeks** after the naturalization test.
> > - If you have not received a result after this period, please contact the BAMF regional office in Berlin directly.
> > - If you have already submitted an application for naturalization to a naturalization authority, the authority will be informed of the result of your examination.

---

**Sources**:

- [Einbürgerung - Berlin.de](https://www.berlin.de/vhs-tempelhof-schoeneberg/kurse/deutsch-als-zweitsprache/pruefungen-und-abschluesse/einbuergerung/)